# Отправка объекта с jsp сервлету

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, request, jstl

У меня есть `jsp` страница, на которой отображается таблица(получаю из "rooms"). По нажатию на кнопку я хочу отправить "сервлету" этот объект "rooms".

Jsp:

```
<c:if test="${not empty rooms}">
  <form action="controller" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="book" />

       <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>id</td>
                        <td>idclass</td>
                        <td>price</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>


                <c:forEach items="${rooms}" var="room">
                    <tr>
                      <td>${room.id}</td>
                      <td>${room.idclass}</td>
                      <td>${room.price}</td>
                    </tr>
                 </c:forEach>

        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Booknow"/>
      </form>
```

Пока получается только с помощью сессии.

Jsp:

```
 <c:set var="roomlist" value="${rooms}" scope="session"/>
```

Servlet:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
List<Room> rooms= (ArrayList<Room>) session.getAttribute("roomlist");
```

Но хранить лист в сессии не вижу особого смысла, хочу передать в запрос.

Попытка с записью в `requst` возвращает в "сервлете" `null`.

Jsp:

```
 <c:set var="roomlist" value="${rooms}" scope="request"/>
```

Servlet:

```
List<Room> rooms= (ArrayList<Room>) request.getAttribute("roomlist");
```

Мне нужен список `id` номеров из таблицы и пока не могу найти нормальный способ их передачи в запрос.
Подскажите как передать объект списка "сервлету" НЕ через сессию или как - то по другому можно передать список `id` из таблицы?

Comment: Ты в сервлете прописал getAttribute.. разве с формы параметры не принимаются?

Comment: getParameter() вернет String, а мне нужен объект ArrayList. Или каким-то образом  создать параметр с массивом id, но пока не могу придумать как это сделать.

Comment: Ааа то есть, ты нажав на submit хочешь взять сразу несколько комнат?

Comment: Хочу получить id всех комнат в таблице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы браузер отправил айдишники комнат на сервер, надо добавить соответствующие поля на форму:

```jsp
<c:forEach items="${rooms}" var="room">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="roomId" value="${room.id}"/>
            ${room.id}
        </td>
        <td>${room.idclass}</td>
        <td>${room.price}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Теперь браузер добавит параметры `roomId=1&roomId=2&...` к запросу.

Чтобы на сервере получить массив переданных айдишников:

```
String[] roomIds = request.getParameterValues("roomId");
// если null, значит ни одного roomId не было передано, заменим на пустой массив
if (roomIds == null) {
    roomIds = new String[0];
}
```